# Vue.js configure root directory when building for production

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am using vue cli 3.6.3.

How can i build a Vue.js project for production if the project is not in the web root?

Inside the webserver the project directory is "my/web/directory"

I start the project using webpack template, and set the publicPath and ROOT_API variables:

```
config/prod.env.js:

'use strict'
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  ROOT_API: '"http://www.example.com/my/web/directory/myapi/myindex.php"',
  publicPath: '/my/web/directory/'
}
```

After a `npm run build` i do upload the dist files (just inside the dist folder: static and index.html) the project point to the webserver root and did not find the js files.

How can i point to the right directory path?

Comment: What does the build `index.html` file show? You could inspect the file and see if the path `/my/web/directory` was added there.

Comment: I just find the assetsPublicPath inside the build section of the config/index.js, i do configure and now it is working fine.

Comment: Post it as an answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

I just find the assetsPublicPath inside the build section of the config/index.js, i do configure and now it is working fine.